# Cannot connect to SharePoint online to create SharePoint App in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, visual-studio, sharepoint-addin

I have an Office 365 account and I am trying to create a SharePoint App via Visual Studio 2013 Here are the steps:
1. Open VS 2013 and select **Office/SharePoint > App for SharePoint** (type the name) then click OK
2. I type in URL of the site (of course https://) and Select **SharePoint-Hosted** option, then click **Finish**
3. I get the Office 365 authentication dialog box. I type in the username and password and it opens the SharePoint in the same rectangular dialog box and it stays there and nothing happens:

[image]

[image]

If I click the close icon on the **Connect to SharePoint** dialog box that still shows my SharePoint online site, I get the following error:
[image]

If I click on **OK** I get the **Connect to SharePoint** dialog box again

[image]

Any idea?? The strange thing I can do this on my other workstation.

Thanks,

Yassar

Answer (score 2):

We built a new system with new load of VS2013 and that worked.  I had the same issue and opened a case with the O365 team.  They could not replicate it. As best I can tell it's an issue with something that happens when you install VS2013 - it changes expected IE behavior.

In my instance if you attempted to browse your DEV site in IE you got the same behavior where it re-directed to the root site collection.  This did not happen with Chrome or Firefox.

What we attempted (none of which worked):
1. Re-Set IE settings / Restart
2. Change default browser to chrome/firefox
3. Repair VS2013 / Restart
4. Removed IE feature / Restart
5. Re-install VS2013
6. Apply VS2013 Update 2 RC.

For comparison can you post your configuration? OS version (assume 8.1 w/IE11) and how it's deployed (bare metal, VHDX, Boot2VHD, etc).

In my case it was a VM running on local Hyper-V not bare metal install.  It was Win 8.1, IE11, VS2013 Update 1.

Comment: I will try your suggestions. Configuration: Windows 7 w/IE 11